# What is parsing? (And differences from search and grep?

Tags: parsing

What exactly is parsing? I mean, generally. How different is parsing different from searching? On command line, if I use the grep tool/command; is that parsing?

For example, if I have just one string:

"Hello world! How are you doing today?"

and I tried to search (using grep or any other tool) whether the word "you" is within that string; is that parsing?

What if I do a web search; for example in Google? Is that parsing?

Or is parsing the name of the process that is a part of the process known as "Search"?

Comment: _analyze (a string or text) into logical syntactic components, typically in order to test conformability to a logical grammar._ - Google

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I did not understand what you just commented. Dumb it down for me please. I'm a newbie; a rookie; a fresher into programming.

Comment: Parsing generally means deconstruct the input into its constituent parts. So, no, searching isn't parsing because there you don't care about - or need to understand - the nature of the parts that don't match the search term, whereas in parsing you categorize everything in the input based on some grammar.

Comment: Searching is just looking for sequences of characters. Parsing checks if the sentence is properly formatted and picks out the parts of the sentence. Ex: "I walk home". A parser reads the sentence, determines that "I" is the subject and "walk" is the verb and determines this is a complete sentence in the English language.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The verb "parse" is essentially related to the word "part", as in "part of speech". (See, for example, the [on-line etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=parse).)

To "parse" a sentence has traditionally meant to break the sentence down into its component parts and identify their relationship with each other. For example, given "I asked a question.", we can parse it into a subject ("I"), a transitive verb in past tense ("asked"), and an object phrase consisting of an article ("a") and a noun ("question"). The parse indicates that the subject performed some action on the object; this is not the same statement as *"A question asked I", and not just because the latter is ungrammatical.

With the advent of computer languages and computational theory, the term "parsing" has been generalized to include analysis of strings which are not human languages. Some people would even use it to simply mean "to divide a string into its component parts", such as "parsing" a line in a CSV file into fields.

It's quite a stretch to apply that to merely searching for a string inside another string, although there may be contexts in which that is an acceptable use of the word. Personally, I would only use it for the action of completely deconstructing a structured string.

Comment: Thank you so much!